# MySQL swap Order in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, swap

I have this table:

```
  ID   |  Name  | GroupORDER |
  1    |  John  |    1       |
  2    |   Ben  |    2       |
  3    |   Joe  |    2       |
  4    |  Paul  |    2       |
  5    |  Anna  |    2       |
  6    |  Tash  |    3       |
  7    |  Ryan  |    3       |
```

I d like to swap with one query the GroupORDER between two groups and have this result:

```
  ID   |  Name  | GroupORDER |
  1    |  John  |    1       |
  6    |  Tash  |    2       |
  7    |  Ryan  |    2       |  
  2    |   Ben  |    3       |
  3    |   Joe  |    3       |
  4    |  Paul  |    3       |
  5    |  Anna  |    3       |
```

Any Ideas?
Something like this totally wrong query:

```
 UPDATE table SET GroupORDER = 2 
 WHERE GroupORDER = 3 AND GroupORDER = 3 WHERE GroupORDER = 2;
```

I am trying to make happen it with one query

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, I have no tested but i think it could work:

```
UPDATE table
SET GroupOrder = 
    CASE 
        WHEN GroupOrder = 2 THEN 3 
        WHEN GroupOrder = 3 THEN 2 
        ELSE GroupOrder 
    END
WHERE GroupOrder = 2 OR GroupOrder = 3;
```

Comment: the same case statement could be used in a SELECT to give the desired result without chaning the data).

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

1. SET GroupORDER = -1 WHERE GroupORDER = 2;
2. SET GroupORDER = 2 WHERE GroupORDER = 3;
3. SET GroupORDER = 3 WHERE GroupORDER = -1;

Comment: This would swap all "2"s with "3"s, which doesn't seem to be the intention of the question.

Comment: This is a way of doing it but I would prefer to make one query to mySql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `id`s to specify the rows to update:

```
UPDATE table
    SET GroupORDER = 3
    WHERE ID in (4, 5);
```

Or, if the names are sufficient:

```
UPDATE table
    SET GroupORDER = 3
    WHERE name in ('Paul', 'Anna');
```

EDIT:

You actually might be able to do what you want, using `limit`:

```
UPDATE table
    SET GroupORDER = 3
    WHERE GroupORDER = 2
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 2;
```

If you don't care which two rows get updated, you can remove the `order by` clause.

Comment: This is not the issue here. I want a solution just using the groupORDER as refrence